# Reading data from a website passing parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session_requests = requests.session()

sw_url = "https://www.southwest.com"
sw_url2 = "https://www.southwest.com/flight/select-flight.html?displayOnly=&int=HOMEQBOMAIR"
#result = session_requests.get(sw_url)

#tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

payload = {"name":"AirFormModel","origin":"MCI","destination":"DAL","departDate":"2018-02-28T06:00:00.000Z","returnDate":"2018-03-03T06:00:00.000Z","tripType":"true","priceType":"DOLLARS","adult":1,"senior":0,"promoCode":""}

#{
#    'origin': 'MCI',
#   'destination': 'DAL',
#   'departDate':'2018-02-28T06:00:00.000Z',
#   'returnDate':'2018-03-01T06:00:00.000Z',
#   'adult':'1'
#}

p = requests.post(sw_url,params=payload)
#print(p.text)
print(p.content)
p1 = requests.get(sw_url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(p.text,'html.parser')

print(soup.find("div",{"class":"productPricing"}))
pr = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"currency_symbol"})

for tag in pr:
    print(tag)
    print('++++')
    print(tag.next_sibling)

print(soup.find("div",{"class":"twoSegments"}))

soup = BeautifulSoup(p1.text,'html.parser')

print(soup.find("div",{"class":"productPricing"}))
pr = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"currency_symbol"})

for tag in pr:
    print(tag)
    print('++++')
    print(tag.next_sibling)

print(soup.find("div",{"class":"twoSegments"}))
```

I need to retrieve prices for flights between 2 locations on specific dates. I identified the parameters by looking at the session info from inspector of the browser and included them in the post request.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I am unable to read the data from the tags correctly. It's printing none.

---

Edit : 4/25/2018

I'm using the following code now, but it doesn't seem to help. Please advise.

```
import threading
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime 
import requests 


def worker(oa,da,ods):
    """thread worker function"""
    print (oa + ' ' + da + ' ' + ods + ' ' +  str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    url = "https://www.southwest.com/api/air-booking/v1/air-booking/page/air/booking/shopping"
    rh = {
    'accept': 'application/json,text/javascript,*/*;q=0.01',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-length': '454',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'referer': 'https://www.southwest.com/air/booking/select.html?originationAirportCode=MCI&destinationAirportCode=LAS&returnAirportCode=&departureDate=2018-05-29&departureTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&returnDate=&returnTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&adultPassengersCount=1&seniorPassengersCount=0&fareType=USD&passengerType=ADULT&tripType=oneway&promoCode=&reset=true&redirectToVision=true&int=HOMEQBOMAIR&leapfrogRequest=true',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
    }

    fd = {
    'returnAirport':'',
    'twoWayTrip':'false',
    'fareType':'DOLLARS',
    'originAirport':oa,
    'destinationAirport':da,
    'outboundDateString':ods,
    'returnDateString':'',
    'adultPassengerCount':'1',
    'seniorPassengerCount':'0',
    'promoCode':'',
    'submitButton':'true'
    }
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.post(url,headers = rh )
#        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
#        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
        print(r)
        print(r.content)
    print (oa + ' ' + da + ' ' + ods + ' ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    return


#db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="vikram",db="garmin")
rcount = 0

tdelta = 55
#print(strt_date)
threads = []
count = 1 
thr_max = 2
r = ["MCI","DEN","MCI","MDW","MCI","DAL"]

strt_date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=tdelta)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

while count < 2:
    t = threading.Thread(name=r[count-1]+r[count],target=worker,args=(r[count-1],r[count],strt_date))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    count = count + 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say looked at the session info from inspector of the browser, I'm assuming you meant the network tab. If that's the case, are you sure you noted the data being sent properly?

Here's the URL that gets sent by the browser, following which the page you required is fetched:

```
url = 'https://www.southwest.com/flight/search-flight.html'
```

You didn't use headers in your request, which, in my opinion, should be passed compulsorily in some cases. Here are the headers that the browser passes:

```
:authority:www.southwest.com
:method:POST
:path:/flight/search-flight.html
:scheme:https
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control:max-age=0
content-length:564
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
origin:https://www.southwest.com
referer:https://www.southwest.com/flight/search-flight.html?int=HOMEQBOMAIR
upgrade-insecure-requests:1
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
```

**Note:**

1. I removed the `cookie` header, because that would be taken care of by requests if you're using session.
2. The first four headers (those that begin with a colon (':')) cannot be passed in Python's `requests`; so, I skipped them.

Here's the `dict` that I used to pass the headers:

```
rh = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'content-length': '564',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'origin': 'https://www.southwest.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.southwest.com/flight/search-flight.html?int=HOMEQBOMAIR',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'
}
```

And here is the form data sent by browser:

```
fd = {
    'toggle_selfltnew': '',
    'toggle_AggressiveDrawers': '',
    'transitionalAwardSelected': 'false',
    'twoWayTrip': 'true',
    'originAirport': 'MCI',
    # 'originAirport_displayed': 'Kansas City, MO - MCI',
    'destinationAirport': 'DAL',
    # 'destinationAirport_displayed': 'Dallas (Love Field), TX - DAL',
    'airTranRedirect': '',
    'returnAirport': 'RoundTrip',
    'returnAirport_displayed': '',
    'outboundDateString': '02/28/2018',
    'outboundTimeOfDay': 'ANYTIME',
    'returnDateString': '03/01/2018',
    'returnTimeOfDay': 'ANYTIME',
    'adultPassengerCount': '1',
    'seniorPassengerCount': '0',
    'promoCode': '',
    'fareType': 'DOLLARS',
    'awardCertificateToggleSelected': 'false',
    'awardCertificateProductId': ''
}
```

Note that I commented out two of the items above, but it didn't make any difference. I assumed you'd be having only the location codes and not the full name. If you do have them or if you can extract them from the page, you can send those as well along with other data.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but I used `data` instead of `params`:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url, headers = rh, data = fd)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

Finally, here is the result:

```
>>> soup.find('span', {'class': 'currency_symbol'}).text
'$'
```

Comment: I think you should show the usage of `requests.Session()` in your program, so that others would understand better and for the sake of completeness. Great answer! +1

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much for the response.I was able to retrieve all the information that I needed. Is your approach faster because you don't need to open a browser at all? Please advise.

Comment: @adf_mobile_developer, yes. I believe using requests is generally better than using selenium, which should always be last resort. Also, to build your script with requests, keep the network tab of developer tools open (F12) while you open the link and select or click objects or submit data. That'll show you the headers and data that actual browsers send.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh! Yes, I see the data I need in the network tab. It is very fast indeed.

Comment: It worked like a charm and it is not working now. Looks like they changed the way content is generated. Do you mind taking a look?